# How to make blur view and still be able to see through partially

Tags: swift, blur

This what requested
[image]

I am trying UIBlurEffect and UIVisualEffectView but not getting to this.
My code:

```
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterialLight)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        blurView.contentView.addSubview(reviewButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            reviewButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48),
            reviewButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            reviewButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            reviewButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
        blurView.frame = bottomView.bounds
        bottomView.addSubview(blurView)
```

What I got so far

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What we do in our app is make a view that draws a gradient that fades from solid to transparent. It covers the scrolling material bottom, so the scrolling material seems to fade as it approaches the button.

Comment: Also if you're going to go with a Material, be sure to check it on the phone, as it is not drawn correctly on the simulator.

Comment: The view containing the button stay fixed at the bottom of the screen and on top of ScrollView.

Comment: Yes, I know. That doesn't affect my answer. Our app has the same design.

Comment: Can you give an example of your gradient? I tried gradient too, but it seems to be see through completely, not blur. Thanks

Comment: That's true, it's not a blur. But the effect is much the same. I suppose you could try masking the blur view with gradient, though I've never tried it and perhaps it doesn't work.